# Why @tasks.loop doesn't works as I think? (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py, task

Hey guys I'm trying to write a dc bot :3

I want to set a background task with cog, and it'll send some message every 5 seconds.
My `Cog_Extension` will initialize by `self.bot = bot`.

My questions are as following:

1. Why the commented part doesn't work?

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cmds.task' raised an error: AttributeError: loop attribute cannot be accessed in non-async contexts. Consider using either an asynchronous main function and passing it to asyncio.run or using asynchronous initialisation hooks such as Client.setup_hook
```

2. Why `await self.bot.wait_until_ready()` has to put in `@tasks.loop`?
   If I don't put it there, the variable `channel` will be None.

Here is my code

```py
class Task(Cog_Extension):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.channel_id = xxx
        self.livingloop.start()

    @tasks.loop(seconds = 5)
    async def livingloop(self):
        await self.bot.wait_until_ready()
        channel = self.bot.get_channel(self.channel_id)
        print(channel)
        await channel.send("blabla")

        # async def interval():
        #     await self.bot.wait_until_ready()
        #     self.channel = self.bot.get_channel(xxx)
        #     while not self.bot.is_closed():
        #         await self.channel.send("blabla")
        #         await asyncio.sleep(5)

        # self.bg_task = self.bot.loop.create_task(interval())
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you need to make your `__init__()` function async.

```py
class Task(Cog_Extension):
    async def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.channel_id = xxx
        self.livingloop.start()
```